# How to receive files via bluetooth in Centos?

Tags: centos, bluetooth

I've read the GNOME Help for Centos 7 in order to receive files from my phone via bluetooth. It suggests me to enable **Bluetooth Sharing** in Settings → Sharing, and switch **Save Received Files to Downloads Folder** to *ON*. However there is no such setting, there are only "remote desktop" and "remote shell" settings. GNOME Help tells that `gnome-user-share` should be installed first. Maybe it is the reason why there is no bluetooth setting in **Sharing**. I've tried `yum install gnome-user-share` but there is no such package available. So, how to receive files via bluetooth in Centos 7 actually?

Answer (score 3):

After encountering this same issue, my conclusion is that the documentation is simply incorrect, and it's not yet possible to utilize `gnome-user-share` out of the box in CentOS 7.

It appears that `gnome-user-share` is not pre-packaged for Centos 7, perhaps because it was a GNOME 2 extension in CentOS 6, whereas CentOS 7 uses GNOME 3 by default.
(See [here](https://pkgs.org/download/gnome-user-share) for quick reference)

Since `gnome-user-share` is released against gnome-shell versions, one could possibly build it themselves for CentOS 7 from the [gnome 3.14 branch](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-user-share/tree/gnome-3-14).

However, it's also possible it is not included in CentOS 7 due to issues with other dependencies, so that may just be a rabbit hole. FWIW, I can confirm fedora includes it at least back to Fedora 24 targeting gnome 3.18
(as I'm typing this, it appears you discovered that based on your more recent [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307358/how-to-receive-files-via-bluetooth-in-fedora-24). )

At any rate, maybe this will save someone else the trouble.

Comment: So, for Centos 7, there is no solution yet? I am sorry it's hard to understand your words :).

Comment: Correct, I do not think there is a solution for CentOS 7 yet. All of the pieces exist and are working with more recent Fedora, but for whatever reason are not packaged for CentOS now.